# Conditional SQL depending on whether the data exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to have conditional SQL queries like so:

I have a form which asks for a maximum value, a minimum value (both required values) and then an option to input 1, 2 or 3 different postcodes.

If there is only 1 postcode entered I want the database to only be queried with the one postcode, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM first_page_data WHERE
value_min > 1
AND
value_max < 5
AND
postcode1 < <<geocode formula here>>
```

But if two or three postcodes are entered I want to change it to:

```
SELECT * FROM first_page_data WHERE
value_min > 1
AND
value_max < 5
AND
(postcode1 < <<geocode formula here>>
OR
postcode2 < <<geocode formula here>>
OR
postcode3 < <<geocode formula here>>)
```

If I just use the bottom query, and there is no data for those second two postcodes then it will return an error. Do I have to manually check for the postcodes using PHP conditional statements and then join them into one query using concatenation, or is there a clever way of doing this right in the SQL query, meaning I can do away with the conditional statements?

---

### EDIT

The geocoding formula which I left out for clarity is the following:

```
((((acos(sin((".$_SESSION['fsea_lat']."*pi()/180)) * sin((`geo_lat1`*pi()/180))+cos((".$_SESSION['fsea_lat']."*pi()/180)) * cos((`geo_lat1`*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$_SESSION['fsea_lon']."- `geo_lon1`)* pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) * (1.609344/1000)) < ".$_SESSION['frange']."
```

Which calculates a distance between a set point and the postcode entered and if it is less than the range variable frange then the condition is satisfied. If any one of the three postcodes satisfy this formula I want the query to return that row.

But of course if there is no data in the postcodes 2 and 3, the formula will be trying to make computations with the NULL in the database table and (while maybe not officially being an error) the result will be erronous!

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you're putting in `<<geocode formula here>>`? And include the specific error you're seeing?

Comment: You could concatenate the postcodes and use the `IN` syntax. Or you can use some conditional PHP statements to build the `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: What do you mean the bottom query "will return an error"?  What is the error?

Comment: updated the question for these comments!

Answer (score 0):

perhaps use the IN construct

```
postcode1 IN (1,2,3)
```